# Hibernate required manytomany relation

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, many-to-many, required

I'm wondering if there is an option in hibernate where I can configure a manytomany field to be required? Normally I would add nullable = false but it can't be added inside these annotations.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(name = "attribuutlabel",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "valueid") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "attribuutlabel") })
private List<Label> labels;
```

Is it even possible in hibernate or should I validate my users input for having associated a label when they use this relation?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Java EE are you using?

If it's EE 6:
add a `@NotNull` on the labels

if it's EE 5:
add `@NotNull`
include Hibernate Validator in the classpath of your app.
include bean validation (JSR 303) api in the classpath of your app.